Plane geometry: how to show a moving point with Mathematica
Point A(a,0), point B(0,a) , say a=5, point C is a point on line segment AB. Connecting OC such that ∠BOC=15 Degree. Point M is a moving point on line AB, constructing an equilateral triangle OMN with OM as a side. Connect CN, what is the minimum value of CN?
The key point should be to find the path of N when point M is moving. The challenge is what is the path of N when point M is moving along AB. It seems to be a straight line, but I cannot prove it so far. I have asked the problem on Math SE. In MMA SE, I want to show the problem dynamically with MMA.
This problem can be refined into: M is a moving point on line segment AB of an isosceles right triangle. Constructing an equilateral triangle OMN with OM as a side. Connect CN, what is the path of N when M is moving?
Thank you very much!

What have you tried?

You haven't asked a question about code that you've tried. You've just asked us to create a solution from scratch.


rotate the Line[{a, b}] around the point {0,0} with 60 Degree.

Clear["Global`*"];
a = {5, 0};
b = {0, 5};
o = {0, 0};
c = RegionIntersection[HalfLine[{0, 0}, AngleVector[75 Degree]], 
    Line[{a, b}]][[1, 1]];
line = TransformedRegion[Line[{a, b}], 
   RotationTransform[60 Degree, {0, 0}]];
m[s_] = {1 - s, s} . {a, b};
p[s_] = RotationTransform[60 Degree, {0, 0}]@m[s];
ani = Manipulate[
  Graphics[{Line[{a, o, b, a}], Line[{o, c}], Red, line, 
    AbsolutePointSize[5], Point@p[s], Blue, Line[{a, b}], Point[m[s]],
     Green, Opacity[.5], Triangle[{o, m[s], p[s]}]}], {s, 0, 1}]



Here is quick and dirty implementation using Manipulate.
It shows the path is straight line.

Code V 14.1
getCordLength[angle_, sideLength_] := Module[{sol, eq1, eq2, h, L},
   eq1 = h^2 == (sideLength - L)^2 + L^2;
   eq2 = h*Cos[angle] == sideLength - L; 
   sol = 
    SelectFirst[N[SolveValues[{eq1, eq2}, {L, h}]], 
     First[#] > 0 && Last[#] > 0 &];
   Last@sol
   ];
a = 5;
lineOA = Line[{{0, 0}, {0, a}}];
lineOB = Line[{{0, 0}, {a, 0}}];
lineAB = Line[{{0, a}, {a, 0}}];
h = getCordLength[75 Degree, a];
ptC = {h Cos[75 Degree], h Sin[75 Degree]}
lineOC = Line[{{0, 0}, ptC}];

Manipulate[
 Module[{ptM, lineOM, lineON, lineMN, lineCN, pt1, pt2, pt3, 
   thePath},
  h = getCordLength[mAngle Degree, a];
  pt1 = {0, 0};
  pt2 = {h Cos[mAngle Degree], h Sin[mAngle Degree]};
  pt3 = {h Cos[(mAngle + 60) Degree], h Sin[(mAngle + 60) Degree]};
  lineOM = {Dashed, Line[{{0, 0}, pt2}]};
  lineON = {Dashed, Line[{{0, 0}, pt3}]};
  lineMN = {Dashed, Line[{pt2, pt3}]};
  lineCN = Line[{ptC, pt3}];
  AppendTo[track, pt3];
  thePath = {Red, Line[track]};
  Print[track];
  Graphics[
   {lineOA, lineOB, lineAB, lineOC, lineOM, lineON, lineMN, thePath,
    Text["N", pt3], Text["M", pt2], Text["C", ptC]},
   PlotRange -> {{-a, a}, {-1, a}}]
  ]
 ,
 {{mAngle, 1, "M angle"}, 1, 89, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{track, {}}, None},
 TrackedSymbols :> {mAngle}
 ]

